# Fragment - how to save/restore hashtable data

Tags: android

I got a fragment with an hashtable contains imageView

```
private HashMap<String, ImageView> mImageViewHashMap = new HashMap<String, ImageView>(30);
```

The fragment is in tabhost, when changing tabs my hashtable resets.

Do i have to to implement onSaveInstanceState ? How should i save the hashtable data ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Shared Preferences` to store the data or every time you need to pass the Hash table data when clicked on tabs...

Comment: i dont need to pass them.. i need to keep them..

when i lock my device screen and unlock it, when coming back to the fragment the view remain the same but the hashtable is empty

Comment: Then Use sharedPreferences, if you use it the values are available until you close the application...

Comment: Also post your complete code....i think your recreating the HashTable somewhere are clearing it...

Answer (score 0):

As for as my understanding you cannot convert ImageView to Serializable object because  ImageView is non-Serializable Object and doesn't have a public no-args constructor.Image view having context. Context objects are not serializable.

Try to use static singleton class to store the temporary views like

```
public class DataStore{
private HashMap<String,ImageView> imageMap = null;
public static void setImageMap(HashMap<String,ImageView> map){
DataStore.imageMap  = map;
}
public static HashMap<String,ImageView> getImageMap(){
return DataStore.imageMap;
}
}
```